# getting munmap_chunk() error while moving lots of files inside bash loop

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash loop like the following that does something inside the loop and moves the results to the proper folders. If I have a small number of files to move script run properly, but if I use it for larger tasks it shows me core dumped. 
I don't know why?

```
#!/bin/bash

g=0.3
tau=5.5

for sim in {0..1}
    do
        ./prog ${g} ${tau}
        mkdir ../data/${sim}
        mkdir ../data/${sim}/cfiles/
        mkdir ../data/${sim}/rfiles/
        mv ../data/cfiles/* ../data/${sim}/cfiles/
        mv ../data/rfiles/* ../data/${sim}/rfiles/
    done

echo "Script Done!"
```

```
Error in `./prog': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000021270f0 
./run.sh: line 12: 14062 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./prog ${g} ${tau}
mv: cannot stat ‘../data/cfiles/*’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘../data/rfiles/*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: are you running out of memory? Check swap partition as well.  This looks like memory allocation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with `prog` rather than the bash script. You'll have to debug the program and work out why it's crashing.

As a starting point, you should find out on which arguments the program crashes. You can do that by printing the arguments from the bash script before running `prog`. The last arguments printed before the crash will be the ones of interest. Hopefully there is no random element and the program will always crash with those arguments.

The next step would be to run the program in a debugger so you can find in which line the crash happens. If you want us to help, you should post the relevant source code from `prog`.